# Pseudoclassical Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am currently working through Javascript the good parts which is a amazingly good book but as the heading saying I seem to be hitting a dead end getting the code to work for chapter
five. When I run the code I am getting nothing in return so I'm not sure where its wrong as its just like the book, any help is great.

```
Function.method('new',function(){
  var that  = Object.beget(this.prototype);
  var other = this.apply(that,arguments);

  return  (typeof other === 'object' && other) || that ;
});

var Mammal = function(name){
  this.name = name;
};

Mammal.prototype.get_name = function(){
  return this.name;
};

Mammal.prototype.says = function(){
  return this.saying || '';
}

var myMammal = new Mammal('Herb the mammal');

var name = myMammal.get_name();

document.writeln(name);
```

Comment: That first part of the code, calling `Function.method` - what is that? Where is that "method" function supposed to come from? Have you checked the developer console for errors?

Comment: [If you get rid of the `Function.method` part of the code it works](http://jsfiddle.net/9E2VX/).

Comment: And Pointy's comment about checking for errors in the console is spot on. It was the first thing I did - that section of code was generating an error and stopping the rest of the code from executing.

Comment: Thanks for the help! works great now. Was re- reading the book as I was waiting and its basically . "If the new operator were a method instead of an operator, it could have been implemented like this" so its nothing to do with the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Please refer 'Augmenting Types' in Chapter 'Functions' of 'JavaScript - The Good Parts'.**

Please add the following code prior to the code posted in the question.

This will make the `method` function available on `Function`.

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
     this.prototype[name] = func;
     return this;
};
```

Please refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbbottam/44udj/) for the complete working code.

Please note `new` method is already available on `Function`. The code displays how to `augment`.

You can get rid of the following blocks from your code.

```
Function.method('new',function(){
  var that  = Object.beget(this.prototype);
  var other = this.apply(that,arguments);

  return  (typeof other === 'object' && other) || that ;
});
```

**But should you need to retain the above block**, you have to `augment` `method` function to `Function`.